# Download files from storage in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I can't download files from storage. Firebug console shows

> FileNotFoundException in File.php line 41: The file
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\ct\storage/30e9734e1f06bf751da5b3289994fb3f/34.pdf"
>   does not exist

But files are existing in `C:\xampp\htdocs\ct\storage\userdata\30e9734e1f06bf751da5b3289994fb3f` folder. I think the file path I mentioned in code is not correct. Please help me to solve this issue.

**filesystems.php**

```
'root'   => storage_path('userdata'),
```

**DownloadController.php**

```
    public function show(TagambitionRequest $request)
        {
            $details             = User::select('id', 'created_at')->findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
            $encrypt             = md5($details->id.$details->created_at);
            $directories         = Storage::files($encrypt);                                             // Listout Files
            foreach($directories as $values)
            {
                $split_folder_file = explode('/', $values);           //60e4dda43c442fe610bdbd4a0e5c3a12/19.pdf
                $splitted_file     = end($split_folder_file);         //19.pdf
                $explode_filename  = explode('.', $splitted_file);    //explode(19.pdf)
                $explode_name      = $explode_filename[0];            //19
                $file_extension    = $explode_filename[1];            //pdf
                if ($file_extension == 'pdf') {
                    $path  = storage_path().'/'.$encrypt.'/'.$splitted_file;
                    return response()->download($path, $splitted_file, ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be on a Windows-computer – then you are using the wrong type of slashes, check your error message.

In Laravel, Flysystem is integrated per default, check the documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem) highly recommended instead of building your own solution.

Comment: Windows can handle slash and backslash even when they are mixed. So this is not the mistake. What happens when you past the path in your windows explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed the `userdata` folder in your path so you need to change

`$path  = storage_path().'/'.$encrypt.'/'.$splitted_file;`

to

`$path  = storage_path().'/userdata/'.$encrypt.'/'.$splitted_file;`